# SciSpacy equivalent of Gensim's functions/parameters

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, gensim

With Gensim, there are three functions I use regularly, for example this one:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(corpus,size=100,min_count=5)
```

The output from gensim, but I cannot understand how to set the size and min_count parameters in the equivalent SciSpacy command of:

```
model = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

(The output is a model of embeddings (too big to add here))).

This is another command I regularly use:

```
model.most_similar(positive=['car'])
```

and this is the output from gensim/Expected output from SciSpacy:

```
[('vehicle', 0.7857330441474915),
 ('motorbike', 0.7572781443595886),
 ('train', 0.7457204461097717),
 ('honda', 0.7383008003234863),
 ('volkswagen', 0.7298516035079956),
 ('mini', 0.7158907651901245),
 ('drive', 0.7093928456306458),
 ('driving', 0.7084407806396484),
 ('road', 0.7001082897186279),
 ('traffic', 0.6991947889328003)]
```

This is the third command I regularly use:

```
print(model.wv['car'])
```

Output from Gensim/Expected output from SciSpacy (in reality this vector is length 100):

```
    [ 1.0942473   2.5680697  -0.43163642 -1.171171    1.8553845  -0.3164575
  1.3645878  -0.5003705   2.912658    3.099512    2.0184739  -1.2413547
  0.9156444  -0.08406237 -2.2248871   2.0038593   0.8751471   0.8953876
  0.2207374  -0.157277   -1.4984075   0.49289042 -0.01171476 -0.57937795...]
```

Could someone show me the equivalent commands for SciSpacy? For example, for 'gensim.models.Word2Vec' I can't find how to specify the length of the vectors (size parameter), or the minimum number of times the word should be in the corpus (min_count) in SciSpacy (e.g. I looked [here](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) and [here](https://github.com/allenai/scispacy)), but I'm not sure if I'm missing them?

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Oh sorry I can add them thanks (will just try to shorten because the expected output for them all is just vectors of numbers, that are embeddings of the words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to achieve your goal would be to:

> 1. parse you documents via `nlp.pipe`
> 2. collect all the words and pairwise similarities
> 3. process similarities to get the desired results

Let's prepare some data:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md", disable = ['ner', 'tagger', 'parser'])
```

Then, to get a vector, like in `model.wv['car']` one would do:

```
nlp("car").vector
```

To get most similar words like `model.most_similar(positive=['car'])` let's process the corpus:

```
corpus = ["This is a sentence about cars. This a sentence aboout train"
          , "And this is a sentence about a bike"]
docs = nlp.pipe(corpus)

tokens = []
tokens_orth = []

for doc in docs:
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.orth_ not in tokens_orth:
            tokens.append(tok)
            tokens_orth.append(tok.orth_)
            
sims = np.zeros((len(tokens),len(tokens)))

for i, tok in enumerate(tokens):
    sims[i] = [tok.similarity(tok_) for tok_ in tokens]
```

Then to retrieve `top=3` most similar words:

```
def most_similar(word, tokens_orth = tokens_orth, sims=sims, top=3):
    tokens_orth = np.array(tokens_orth)
    id_word = np.where(tokens_orth == word)[0][0]
    sim = sims[id_word]
    id_ms = np.argsort(sim)[:-top-1:-1]
    return list(zip(tokens_orth[id_ms], sim[id_ms]))


most_similar("This")
```

---

```
[('this', 1.0000001192092896), ('This', 1.0), ('is', 0.5970357656478882)]
```

---

PS

I have also noticed you asked for specification of dimension and frequency. Embedding length is fixed at the time the model is initialized, so it can't be changed after that. You can start from a blank model if you wish so, and feed embeddings you're comfortable with. As for the frequency, it's doable, via counting all the words and throwing away anything that is below desired threshold. But again, underlying embeddings will be from a not filtered text. SpaCy is different from Gensim in that it uses readily available embeddings whereas Gensim trains them.

Comment: great thanks. For embedding length, I'm trying to replicate the gensim vector size: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#vector-size ('is the number of dimensions (N) of the N-dimensional space that gensim Word2Vec maps the words onto'). But can I confirm that what you're saying is that the length is set when you load in the model (i.e. the vector length is 300 for the whole model/vocab when you do nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_md"))...that's what I gathered from: https://www.shanelynn.ie/word-embeddings-in-python-with-spacy-and-gensim/

Comment: >>> `the length is set when you load in the model`. It's set at the time somebody loads vectors into an empty model and proceeds to training pos, dependency parser and ner. You can't change vectors afterwards -- when you load a trained model --  as the trained pipelines are based on embeddings. Surely you can use your embeddings, it's several hours exercise, but what is the point of doing that, unless you want a language model that is not available.